# Symfony 4: Implement links routes with Hateoas-Bundle

Tags: rest, serialization, deserialization, hateoas, symfony4

I try the install "willdurand/hateoas-bundle" inside my project with Symfony4 but there is a problem because the "HATEOAS-BUNDLE" only working with Symfony3 and below. [requires symfony/framework-bundle ~2.3 - v3.4.3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zuP4W.png)

In this case I used [willdurand/hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) but I checked and there is not have BazingaHateoasBundle and I think there is my problem because I can not perform the Serialization links in this way:

```
{
    "user": {
        "id": 3,
        "played_name": "John",
        "_links": {
            "self": { "href": "http://example.com/person/3" }
        }
    }
}
```

It only shows me the data without serialization links:

```
{
    "id": 3,
    "played_name": "John Doe"
}
```

In Symfony 3 and below, the [hateos-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/willdurand/hateoas-bundle) include this package [BazingaHateoasBundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle)):

```
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array(new Bazinga\Bundle\HateoasBundle\BazingaHateoasBundle());
    }
}
```

And the [willdurand/Hateoas](https://github.com/willdurand/Hateoas) for Symfony 4 there is not include the BazingaHateoasBundle

And When configure the Serialization Link in my Entity Role

@Hateoas\Relation("person", href=@Hateoas\Route("get_human", parameters={"person" = "expr(object.getPerson().getId())"})

The response is only the data without serialization link:

[Postman Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvF55.png)

There would be a way for serialization links to be made with Hateoas in Symfony 4?

Comment: Okay, I think I found the solution to my problem The "willdurand/hateoas-bundle" is already compatible with SF4 But only if is install in dev-master                                                   
                                                                                                    
`composer require willdurand/hateoas-bundle:dev-master`

Comment: Thanks, that works. May I ask why you chose to use willdurand/hateoas-bundle and not willdurand/hateoas?

Comment: Because the willdurand/hateoas not include BazingaHateoasBundle and this package is required for create hypermedia links.

Comment: You didn't mention which version of `willdurand/hateoas-bundle` you use, `^2.0` still use BazingaHateoasBundle ("^3.1") and works with Symfony 4